# LibGDX textures do not appear after reloading

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm working with an app which is using `OpenGL ES` through `libgdx`. There are undo/redo functions in my app. When the user clicks one of the buttons, the image in the app (which was created via OpenGL ES) is disposed. After that, in the OpenGL thread is loading a new image. Redo is doing the same function. Sometimes when I click undo/redo, the image in `ImageView` becomes black, sometimes text in `TextView` becomes black. I think the problem is in `dispose()` method, but I don't understand why the image and text becomes black. Maybe someone can help me.
Code of dispose:

```
if(obj.getTexture() != null){
    obj.getTexture().dispose();
}
```

Code of load texture:

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.absolute(fileName));
```

Undo code:

```
int indexUndo = undoObjects.size() - 1;
SpriteState ss = undoObjects.get(indexUndo);
if(object instanceof PhotoSprite){
     PhotoSpriteState pState = (PhotoSpriteState)ss;
     if(pState.getTypeChanging() == TypeSpriteChanging.ChangeTexture){
        object.saveRedoState(TypeSpriteChanging.ChangeTexture);
        PhotoSprite photoObj = (PhotoSprite)object;
        photoObj.setFileName( pState.getFilename() );
        photoObj.setGeometry( pState.getGeometry() );
        photoObj.setTexture(null);
     }
}
```

Redo code:

```
int indexRedo = redoObjects.size() - 1;
SpriteState ss = redoObjects.get(indexRedo);
if(object instanceof PhotoSprite){
     PhotoSpriteState pState = (PhotoSpriteState)ss;
     if(pState.getTypeChanging() == TypeSpriteChanging.ChangeTexture){
        object.saveRedoState(TypeSpriteChanging.ChangeTexture);
        PhotoSprite photoObj = (PhotoSprite)object;
        photoObj.setFileName( pState.getFilename() );
        photoObj.setGeometry( pState.getGeometry() );
        photoObj.setTexture(null);
     }
}
```

Code laod texture:

```
public void render(PhotoSprite psObject, int zIndex) {
    ShaderProgram shader = psObject.getShader();
    if(!shader.isCompiled()){
        Log.i("ERROR", "SHERROR " + shader.getLog());
    }
    if(psObject.getTexture() == null){
        psObject.setTexture(loadTexture(FILE_PATH + psObject.getFileName()));
    }
    psObject.getTexture().bind(0);

    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", psObject.getMatrix(zIndex));
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    // psObject.getMesh()
    MeshUtil.MESH.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    shader.end();
}
```

Initial state:

[image]

After using undo/redo

[image]

Comment: We need to see *way* more code than this. The bug is somewhere in your undo/redo logic.

Comment: Show us how you handle the different lifecycle callbacks... show, hide, pause, resume...

Comment: Sorry, I added code undo/redo. About show, hide, pause, resume, show and hide wasn't realized. In pause and resume, I don't have work with OpenGL, and this methods don't call when user click undo/redo

Comment: You will need to show the part of your code that disposes and the part that reloads the texture. There is not enough context here to see what is happening to your texture. Also, are you using actual Android ImageViews, or do you mean LibGDX sprites?

Comment: I added code which texture is loading. In ImageView, texture is hiding. With opengl texture is all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answer. Problem was in destroy texture out of GLThread. Hope it will help someone.